# Selenium+Python, about find_element_by_xpath h3

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

Is there any way identify the button "Connect" by the string "Test Engine 0728" then click it with the method find_element_by_xpath or any other method in python+selenium environment. Thanks a lot!

```
<html
 <head
 <body
  <div class="page" id="main-page"
   <div class="controls" id="Engines"
     <div class="devices" id="Devices-List"
         <h3 class="device-name">Test Engine 0728 </h3>
     </div>
     <button>Connect</button>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath should work for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Test Engine 0728')]/../../button[contains(text(),'Connect')]").click()
```

Comment: Clear and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly multiple ways to find the button.

One option would be to start your xpath expression with the `div` with id `Engines`, check that it contains the `h3` tag with `Test Engine 0728` text in the `div` with `Devices-List` id. Then, get the `button` by `Connect` text:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="Engines" and div[@id="Devices-List"]/h3[contains(., "Test Engine 0728")]]/button[. = "Connect"]')
button.click()
```

Or, another option would be to find the `div` with `Devices-List` id, check for the `h3` tag's text inside and get the following button sibling:

```
//div[@id="Devices-List" and h3[contains(., "Test Engine 0728")]]/following-sibling::button
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also should work:

```
connectButtonClick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='controls'][@id='Engines'][contains(., 'Test Engine 0728')]//button[text()='Connect']").click()
```